# How to get the coordinate x of a progress bar in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to set the width of a progress bar using javascript, but I could not get the right width of the progress bar.

```
<div id="defaultBar"> 
  <div id="progressbar"></div>
</div>


var bar = document.getElementById("defaultBar");
var progressBar = document.getElementById("progressbar");
    bar.addEventListener("click", clickBar, false);

function clickBar(event){
    var x = event.pageX - bar.offsetLeft;
    var time = x * audio.duration/barSize;
    audio.currentTime = time;
    progressBar.style.width = x + 'px';
}
```

Comment: is the bar a `progress` element? You'll want it's `value`, no it's length/width. Can you show your html/js

Comment: thanks for ur help. What I wanna do is dynamically adding progress bar as playing songs. htm: <audio id="my-audio"></audio> <div id="defaultBar"><div id="progressbar"></div></div>

Comment: so you are creating a fake progress bar rather then use `progress`? vthere is an article here (http://www.adobe.com/devnet/archive/html5/articles/html5-multimedia-pt3.html) that does something like that (for some reason)

Comment: that's a useful article. but when I click the progress bar, I wanna update its width too. but I can not get the correct coordinate. what I got of X was longer than its supposed to be. I dont know what the problem

Comment: @atmd I got the problem solved. thanks very much for the article

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 var x = event.offsetX
```

to get the X cordinate of the mouse pointer between that event and the padding edge of the target node.